# Setting Up Google Mock 1.6

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, googlemock

I'm trying to follow along with *Modern C++ Programming with Test-Driven Development* and to do so the book instructs readers to install 
Google Mock 1.6. Trying to do I downloaded the source from [here](https://github.com/google/googlemock/releases/tag/release-1.6.0). Then according to the book I do:
`mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make`

```
myComputer:build me$ cmake ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 8.0.0.8000042
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 8.0.0.8000042
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:56 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source "../gtest" which is not an existing
  directory.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:61 (config_compiler_and_linker):
  Unknown CMake command "config_compiler_and_linker".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/me/Downloads/googlemock-release-1.6.0 3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

The ../gtest directory is indeed missing. As these are the directories:

```
CHANGES     COPYING     build       include     scripts
CMakeLists.txt  Makefile.am build-aux   make        src
CONTRIBUTORS    README      configure.ac    msvc        test
```

Adding to the confusion are these instructions:

```
You will also need to build Google Test, which is nested within Google Mock.

cd $GMOCK_HOME/gtest
mkdir mybuild
cd mybuild
cmake ..
make
```

I looked at the README and I don't seem anything that helps resolve this issue. Any help/guidance would be super!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/google/googlemock), Google Mock has been absorbed into the [GoogleTest project](https://github.com/google/googletest).

There are various ways to install GoogleTest, described in [The GoogleTest Readme](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md). Since you seem to be using CMake, I suggest you follow the steps under

> Incorporating Into An Existing CMake Project

You can also put everything that should go into CMakeLists.txt into CMakeLists.GTest and then only put `include(CmakeLists.GTest)` in CMakeLists.txt.

If you want to determine a fixed version of GoogleTest that should be incorporated, you can use the `GIT_TAG` eg `release-1.8.0´ instead of`master` in your CMakeLists.txt.in.

After incorporating GoogleTest in your project, you can add gtests for class `Foo` by creating eg FooTest.cpp that includes `gtest/gtest.h` and `Foo.h`. Therefore, you also have to put `add_executable(FooTarget FooTest.cpp)` and `target_link_libraries(FooTarget gtest)` in the corresponding CMakeLists.txt.

You can also find a short description of this, and how to integrate GoogleTests into ctest on [these slides](https://github.com/CppUgKa/Treffen/blob/master/Treff5/2_EffektivesTestenMitCpp_David.pdf)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have gtest inside gmock dir.
I initialy had same error as you, than took gtest version 1.6 from https://github.com/google/googletest and placed it in gmock root dir and succesfully built it.